# Разные значения слова "радикал"

Tags: заимствования, омонимы

Вопрос, может быть, не только по русскому языку, но и по математике, химии и т.д. Но вот меня интересует, почему у слова "радикал" столько не связанных друг с другом значений. "Радикал" — человек крайних взглядов. "Радикал" — синоним математического корня. "Радикал" — в химии: свободный ион. Я не вижу тут даже отдаленной связи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу не привести блестящее высказывание Дж. Литлвуда (по памяти).
"*Радикал* для математика и для полицмейстера означают совершенно разные вещи".

Вообще латинское radix - "корень" выступает в двух значениях, едва ли не противоположных по смыслу. Условно говоря: коренной (сущностный) и корневой (периферийный или способный к изменениям), отсюда некоторая путаница. В отношении политики - трактовка не совсем точная. 
Радикальные взгляды - идеология, основанная на необходимости **коренных изменений**, а совсем не за "основы" - это удел консерваторов, которых как раз противопоставляют радикалам.    
В биологии и химии - тоже способный к изменениям.  
В математике и  лингвистике - коренной, сущностный.
и проч.
Дальше разберетесь, надеюсь.

Answer (score 3):

Радикал, в буквальном переводе с латыни - коренной, отсюда и все его значения.

Радикал в математике - корень.
Радикал в политике - человек бескомпромиссных взглядов, выступающий за коренные изменения.
Радикал в химии - свободный атом,  сохранивший часть структуры молекулы, или в понимании Лувуазье, способный перейти из одного соединения в другое без изменений.
Радикал в лингвистике - простой иероглиф в составе сложного (иероглифический ключ).

Comment: > Радикал в химии - свободный атом, сохранивший часть структуры молекулы, или в понимании Лувуазье, способный перейти из одного соединения в другое без изменений.

Не совсем. Радикалом может быть целая группа атомов со свободной валентностью. Не знаю как сказать это более конкретно.